# i7-7700 - Am I missing some cores?

Tags: cpu, cpu-cores

According to the information on the [intel website](https://ark.intel.com/products/97128/Intel-Core-i7-7700-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_20-GHz), the `intel core i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz` has 4 cores. When I have a look into my system information at `msinfo32` it tells me that I have `2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)`. Am I missing 2 cores?

Comment: If you're on windows try Ctrl+Shift+Esc and check in the resources monitor under Resources's tab

Comment: This is my [resource monitor](https://puu.sh/BnHj1/dfb407923d.png). It says I have CPU0, CPU1, CPU2 and CPU3.

Comment: Are you positive you have an i7-7700? Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I have an i7-7700 @ 3.60GHz as can be seen in [this picture](https://puu.sh/BnMyn/ab4052999c.png)

Comment: May be is a driver issue, or maybe is something related to BIOS configuration. Try to enter to your BIOS Setup and check there

Comment: I ran Driver Booster 6, updated all drivers and had a look into my CPU Bios [settings](https://puu.sh/Bxvlz/d8b87c6aa3.jpg). Unfortunately, the problem still persists.